# why C# standard message loop doesn't heavily increase CPU usage

Tags: c#

So far I learned that, a standard message loop in C# looks like this:

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{ 
   TranslateMessage(&msg); 
   DispatchMessage(&msg); 
}
```

But what I'm wondering is, how it keeps the CPU usage low and the responsive time is fine(in a windows form scenario) ?
is it because it sets the thread with a low priority or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

Because GetMessage doesn't return instantly, it blocks while waiting leaving the CPU free to do other things